# How can I bulk delete Prospects in Pardot?

Tags: pardot, bulk-delete

On the Salesforce end of things we've implemented some logic to prevent certain contacts ever syncing to Pardot and in test it seems to work as planned, but we still have 924 prospects in Pardot that went across before the changes were made.

What's the easiest way to bulk delete a list of prospects in Pardot?  I have the Prospect IDs and Email addresses in a CSV file, but there's no equivalent to Salesforce Data Loader for Pardot

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a segmentation rule to place all your unwanted prospects onto a list. Then select all prospects. using 'table actions' you'd be able to delete all your desired prospects.

However, you should note that this places prospects in the recycle bin. So if that prospect has activity e.g submits a form, the prospect will be returned to the main prospect list.

Unfortunately prospects cannot be permanently deleted by a user. I'd get in touch with support, to do a deletion off the backend.

See documentation here: http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2125906-deleting-prospects?b_id=11139

Comment: Thanks Richard - due to regulation, we need to permanently delete them, so good to know what is and isn't possible in this regard

Comment: I'd contact Pardot support and request it's for regulatory reasons, so they should be able to help